# VS2022 - Android TV Emulator - add app to homescreen?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using VS2022 to develop a Blazor Hybrid App which I have running on a number of emulators.

I'm just wondering after deploying to the Android TV emulator, how to get the app to appear in the 'apps' menu or on the home screen.

I can open the settings, all apps and see the app-icon, but can't work out how to get it to show on those two menus.

I'm using the Android TV API 33 emulator (standard) on Windows 10.

Comment: google for `LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` ... it seem like first result is the official google documentation

Comment: I assume that you are using xamarin than you also need to look at IntentFilter  attribute

Comment: I am using Maui Blazor Hybrid.  It already contains the LEANBACK_LAUNCHER setting under the tvActivity activity.

Comment: If of use: the MainActivity has MainLauncher=true, but no other reference indicating it may be also run on AndroidTV (as well as Pixel).

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the two comments, I eventually got it to work.

I had to add the *IntentFilter* attribute for the LEANBACK_LAUNCHER to the MainActivity class.

I then needed to add two *uses-features* to the AndroidManifest.xml; One for Leanback set to false, the other for touchscreen, also set to false.

Finally, I needed to set my 'SupportedOSPlatformVersion' in the project settings to be 33.0 for Android. This was just required to get my project to build.

The result is that I can now deploy to both a Pixel emulator and Android TV emulator.